# Twitter bootstrap dropdown not working?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked into every threads in stackoverflow but couldn't solve my issue. Here's my head element:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/custom.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />


        <!-- Javascript imports-->

        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



        <title>Rank Analyzer</title>
        <meta name="author" content="zurelsoft" />
        <!-- Date: 2013-07-18 -->
    </head>
```

I am calling dropdown in body like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
         <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>test</a>
         <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Ban</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="i"></i> Make admin</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

The dropdown is not showing up. Am I missing something?

Comment: are you calling `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` anywhere? you don't "call" dropdown from html...

Comment: I haven't. But as you say, I added but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Have you initialize the dropdown?

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

the html structure of the dropdown menu

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The structure of your dropdown html isn't very good... But it should work, have you try to use the normal structure of the dropdown? (look at the comment, i edit it)

Answer (score 2):

It must work. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/gyzRY/).
It seems to me that you're trying to include your bootstrap library twice.

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why don't you just use this library: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js or it's minified version: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
which would include all the components.

As an alternative you can include every single twitter bootstrap component (as they do in their [page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html)) but you cannot include the full package library.

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
```

Comment: My problem was including bootstrap twice. This answer helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I placed **jquery.js above bootstrap.js** and worked for me. If in case this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You might want to restructure the code.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-user icon-white"> Test <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Ban</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Make Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```